# How can I get the ActorRef from the Receptionist so my actor can send messages to that actor

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

So I have 2 actors, `ClientIn` and `Maker`.

I need to have a reference of Maker inside of ClientIn, so I can forward some messages that `ClientIn` recieves to `Maker`.

I added `Maker` to the `receptionist`, but since `clientIn` is created first, and `maker` 2nd I'm not sure how to query to fetch the actorRef.

**Actually I'm just confused how I can now query the receptionist so that clientIn will get the reference to the Maker actor.**

Here is what I have:

// guardian actor constructor:

```
Behaviors.setup[Any] { context =>
    implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = context.executionContext

    val system = context.system

    val clientIn = context.spawn(ClientIn(), "ClientIn")

    val maker = context.spawn(Maker(clientOut), "mmaker")

    ....

}
```

ClientIn.scala:

```
object ClientIn {
  sealed trait ClientInCommand
  case class Watch(symbol: String) extends ClientInCommand
  case class Command(value: String) extends ClientInCommand
  private case class ListingResponse(listing: Receptionist.Listing)
      extends ClientInCommand

  def apply(): Behavior[ClientInCommand] = {

    Behaviors.setup { context =>
      context.log.info(s"ClientIn starting...${context.self}")

      val listingResponseAdapter =
        context.messageAdapter[Receptionist.Listing](ListingResponse.apply)

      var maker: Option[ActorRef[Maker.MMCommand]] = None

      Behaviors.receiveMessage[ClientInCommand] {
        case Watch(symbol) =>
          context.log.info(s"ClientIn watch message received..$symbol")
          Behaviors.same
        case Command(value) =>
          context.log.info(s"ClientInCommand.Command with value:$value")

          // TODO: Maker ! RecieveCommand(value)
          Behaviors.same
        case ListingResponse(Maker.makerKey.Listing(listings)) =>
          maker = Some(listings.head)
          Behaviors.same

      }
    }

  }
}
```

Maker.scala:

```
object Maker {
  val makerKey = ServiceKey[MMCommand]("makerKey")

  sealed trait MMCommand
  case object Startup extends MMCommand
  case object Shutdown extends MMCommand

  def apply(): Behavior[MMCommand] = {

    Behaviors.setup { context =>

      context.system.receptionist ! Receptionist.Register(
        makerKey,
        context.self
      )

      Behaviors.receiveMessage[MMCommand] {
        case Startup =>
          context.log.info("Maker startup message received..")
          Behaviors.same
        case Shutdown =>
          context.log.info("Maker shutdown message received..")
          Behaviors.same
      }

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send a `Receptionist.Subscribe(Maker.makerKey)` message to the receptionist, as described in the Akka documentation on [Actor discovery](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actor-discovery.html):

```
context.system.receptionist ! Receptionist.Subscribe(Maker.makerKey, listingResponseAdapter)
```

Quoting the documentation:

> It will send Listing messages to the subscriber, first with the set of entries upon subscription, then whenever the entries for a key are changed.

This allows it to receive the maker `ActorRef` even if it is registered with the receptionist after the `ClientIn` actor is spawned. However, it is possible in principle that `ClientIn` may receive other messages such as `Command` before this happens. It will need to handle these cases, perhaps by [stashing](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/stash.html) or dropping commands until the `Maker` has been registered.

In this specific example, it would be simpler to avoid this requirement by spawning the `Maker` first, and passing its `ActorRef` to `ClientIn.apply`:

```
val maker = context.spawn(Maker(), "mmaker")
val clientIn = context.spawn(ClientIn(maker), "ClientIn")
```

Then, in `ClientIn`:

```
def apply(maker: ActorRef[Maker.MMCommand]): Behavior[ClientInCommand] = {
  Behaviors.setup { context =>
    context.log.info(s"ClientIn starting...${context.self}")
    Behaviors.receiveMessage[ClientInCommand] {
      case Watch(symbol) =>
        context.log.info(s"ClientIn watch message received..$symbol")
        Behaviors.same
      case Command(value) =>
        context.log.info(s"ClientInCommand.Command with value:$value")
        maker ! Maker.ReceiveCommand(value)
        Behaviors.same
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the `ActorRef` returned from `spawn` is able to receive messages immediately, even if the actor hasn't fully initialized.